# what is the difference between keyguardlock.reenableKeyguard() and DevicePolicyManager.locknow()?

Tags: android

**i wanted to known what is the difference between**

```
 KeyguardManager localKeyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService("keyguard");
String str1 = getClass().toString();
  keyguardlock = localKeyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(str1);
  keyguardlock.reenableKeyguard();
```

**and**

```
mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
            mAM = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(Controller.this, UnLockAdminReceiver.class);

            setContentView(R.layout.main);


Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN); intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminSample);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Additional text explaining why this needs to be added.");
        startActivity(intent); 
        mDPM.lockNow();
```

*** what is the benefit of locking the android with DevicePolicyManager and i also need to known whether we can use DevicePolicyManager to unlock the phone***

Answer (score 0):

The keyguardLock method lock the screen and the DevicePolicyManager locks method lock the device